# Assistance with a table to add values in rows and delete them with a button. Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I would like to create a table that will prompt you to add your name and occupation and add them in a row in the table. The values are supposed to go into an array. The delete button will delete them from the array and remove the row. There is supposed to be a counter as well.

At the moment I tried to do it only for the array `peopleArray[]`. I encounter the issue that the remove button will not work outside the function for "add" and executes many times, deleting everything in the array with just one click. I am misplacing something.

```css
* {
  font-family: verdana;
}

.table-container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table tr {
  text-align: center;
}

.table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.table tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #fcfafa;
}

.table th {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #A9BABA;
  color: #000;
}

.table th:first-child,
.table th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15px;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.btn_img {
  width: 20px;
}

.button_style {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button_style:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.button_style:focus {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  outline: none;
}

table td {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th class="">No.</th>
        <th class="">Name</th>
        <th class="">Occupation</th>
        <th class="">
          <button id="btn_add_people" class="button_style"><img class="btn_img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6FXVi7B.png" alt="options">
            </button></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="counter" class="counter" colspan="4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var peopleArray = [];
      var occupArray = [];
      var countP = 0;

      $("#btn_add_people").click(function() {
        var personName = prompt("Enter a name please!");
        var personOccup = prompt("Enter an occupation please!");

        peopleArray.push(personName);
        occupArray.push(personOccup);
        countP = peopleArray.length
        var addedRow = '<tr id=""><td colspan="1" >' + peopleArray.length + '</td><td id="name' + peopleArray.length + '" colspan="1">' + peopleArray[peopleArray.length - 1] + '</td><td colspan="1">' + occupArray[occupArray.length - 1] + '</td><td colspan="1"><button id="' + peopleArray.length + '" class="button_style btn_remove_person"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eiyNHjs.png" alt="close" class="btn_img" /></button></td></tr>';

        $(".table").append(addedRow);
        $("#counter").text("People added: " + countP);


        $("tr").on('click', '.btn_remove_person', (function() {
          $(this).parents("tr").remove()
          var exitN = $(this).attr("id");
          peopleArray.splice(exitN - 1, 1);
          // get ID from button and connect with ID to splice name and occupation !!! 
          $("#counter").text("People added: " + countP);
        }));

      });
      
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `$(document).ready(function() {    });` as you are not really making great use of it. If you wanted to keep it to prevent users from entering information, then hide the add button first, then in the `.ready` display the button to indicate it is ready to use.

Keep the JQuery for adding entries but when creating the delete button add a onclick function to delete the entry.

I leave your counter calculations up to you as I do not know how you want to make the counters..people added being a total number to include deleted entries? People added being a count of entries in the table? Number next to entry being row number or could be 23 and 22 before it were deleted, etc...

```
var peopleArray = [];
var occupArray = [];
var countP = 0;

$("#btn_add_people").click(function() {
    var personName = prompt("Enter a name please!");
    var personOccup = prompt("Enter an occupation please!");

    peopleArray.push(personName);
    occupArray.push(personOccup);
    countP = peopleArray.length

    var addedRow = '<tr id=""><td colspan="1" >' + peopleArray.length  + '</td><td id="name' + peopleArray.length + '" colspan="1">' + peopleArray[peopleArray.length - 1] + '</td><td colspan="1">' + occupArray[occupArray.length - 1] + '</td><td colspan="1"><button id="' + peopleArray.length  + '" class="button_style btn_remove_person" onclick="_removeEntry(this)">Delete</button></td></tr>';

    $(".table").append(addedRow);   
    $("#counter").text("People added: " + countP);
});

function _removeEntry(e) {  
    $(e).parents("tr").remove()
    var exitN = $(e).attr("id");
    peopleArray.splice(exitN - 1, 1);
    $("#counter").text("People added: " + countP);
};
```